How to change the whole app language settings at once in runtime , android kotlin
I have a android app in kotlin where I have multiple activity. I want to change the language at runtime.
This is what I have tried---
This is the storage class
class Storage(context: Context) {
    private var preferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Helper.PREF_SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    fun getPreferredLocale(): String {
        Log.d("CheckLanguageLocale", "getPreferredLocale: --${preferences.getString("preferred_locale", LocaleUtil.OPTION_PHONE_LANGUAGE)!!}")
        return preferences.getString("preferred_locale", LocaleUtil.OPTION_PHONE_LANGUAGE)!!
    }

    fun setPreferredLocale(localeCode: String) {
        preferences.edit().putString("preferred_locale", localeCode).apply()
    }
}

This is the applications class
class MyApp: Application() {
    val storage : Storage by lazy {
        Storage(this)
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        Log.d("CheckLanguageLocale", "attach base context get call")

        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleUtil.getLocalizedContext(base, Storage(base).getPreferredLocale()))
    }
}

This is the localeUtil class
class LocaleUtil {
    companion object {
        val supportedLocales = listOf("en", "bn")
        const val OPTION_PHONE_LANGUAGE = "sys_def"

        /**
         * returns the locale to use depending on the preference value
         * when preference value = "sys_def" returns the locale of current system
         * else it returns the locale code e.g. "en", "bn" etc.
         */
        fun getLocaleFromPrefCode(prefCode: String): Locale {
            val localeCode = if(prefCode != OPTION_PHONE_LANGUAGE) {
                prefCode
            } else {
                val systemLang = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().configuration).get(0)!!.language
                if(systemLang in supportedLocales){
                    systemLang
                } else {
                    "en"
                }
            }
            return Locale(localeCode)
        }

        fun getLocalizedConfiguration(prefLocaleCode: String): Configuration {
            val locale = getLocaleFromPrefCode(prefLocaleCode)
            return getLocalizedConfiguration(locale)
        }

        fun getLocalizedConfiguration(locale: Locale): Configuration {
            val config = Configuration()
            return config.apply {
                config.setLayoutDirection(locale)
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    config.setLocale(locale)
                    val localeList = LocaleList(locale)
                    LocaleList.setDefault(localeList)
                    config.setLocales(localeList)
                } else {
                    config.setLocale(locale)
                }
            }
        }

        fun getLocalizedContext(baseContext: Context, prefLocaleCode: String): Context {
            val currentLocale = getLocaleFromPrefCode(prefLocaleCode)

            val baseLocale = getLocaleFromConfiguration(baseContext.resources.configuration)
            Locale.setDefault(currentLocale)
            return if (!baseLocale.toString().equals(currentLocale.toString(), ignoreCase = true)) {
                val config = getLocalizedConfiguration(currentLocale)
                baseContext.createConfigurationContext(config)
            } else {
                baseContext
            }
        }
        fun applyLocalizedContext(baseContext: Context, prefLocaleCode: String) {
            val currentLocale = getLocaleFromPrefCode(prefLocaleCode)
            Log.d("CheckLanguageLocale", "currentLocale on applyLocalizedContext --$currentLocale")
            val baseLocale = getLocaleFromConfiguration(baseContext.resources.configuration)
            Log.d("CheckLanguageLocale", "baseLocale on applyLocalizedContext --$baseLocale")
            Locale.setDefault(currentLocale)
            if (!baseLocale.toString().equals(currentLocale.toString(), ignoreCase = true)) {
                val config = getLocalizedConfiguration(currentLocale)
                Log.d("CheckLanguageLocale", "config --$config")
                baseContext.resources.updateConfiguration(config, baseContext.resources.displayMetrics)
            }
        }

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        private fun getLocaleFromConfiguration(configuration: Configuration): Locale {
            return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                configuration.locales.get(0)
            } else {
                configuration.locale
            }
        }

        fun getLocalizedResources(resources: Resources, prefLocaleCode: String): Resources {
            val locale = getLocaleFromPrefCode(prefLocaleCode)
            val config = resources.configuration
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            config.locale = locale
            config.setLayoutDirection(locale)

            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
            return resources
        }
    }
}

This is the Activity code where I am changing the language
class ChangeAppLanguageActivity : BaseActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityChangeAppLanguageBinding
    private lateinit var firstLocaleCode: String
    private lateinit var secondLocaleCode: String
    private lateinit var currentSystemLocaleCode: String
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityChangeAppLanguageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.toolbar.backBtn.setOnClickListener {
            navigation()
        }
        binding.toolbar.userProfilePhoto.setOnClickListener {
            goToAccount(this)
        }
        setProfile(this, binding.toolbar.userProfilePhoto)
      /*  binding.rlEnglish.setOnClickListener {

            startActivity( Intent(this, AccountScreen::class.java))
        }*/
        currentSystemLocaleCode = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().configuration).get(0)!!.language
        if(storage.getPreferredLocale() == LocaleUtil.OPTION_PHONE_LANGUAGE){
            if(currentSystemLocaleCode in LocaleUtil.supportedLocales){
                binding.tvAppLocale.text = getString(R.string.phone_language, Locale(currentSystemLocaleCode).displayLanguage)
            } else {
                //current system language is neither English nor my second language (for me Bangla)
                binding.tvAppLocale.text = "English"
            }
        } else {
            if(currentSystemLocaleCode == storage.getPreferredLocale()){
                binding.tvAppLocale.text = getString(R.string.phone_language, Locale(currentSystemLocaleCode).displayLanguage)
            } else {
                binding.tvAppLocale.text = Locale(storage.getPreferredLocale()).displayLanguage
            }
        }
        firstLocaleCode = if(currentSystemLocaleCode in LocaleUtil.supportedLocales){
            currentSystemLocaleCode
        } else {
            if(storage.getPreferredLocale() == LocaleUtil.OPTION_PHONE_LANGUAGE){
                //current system language is neither English nor my second language (for me Bangla)
                "en"
            } else {
                storage.getPreferredLocale()
            }
        }
        secondLocaleCode = getSecondLanguageCode()
        initRadioButtonUI()
        binding.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
            when (checkedId) {
                R.id.op1 -> {
                    updateAppLocale(LocaleUtil.OPTION_PHONE_LANGUAGE)

                    //recreate()
                    startActivity(Intent(this,AccountScreen::class.java))
                }
                R.id.op2 -> {
                    updateAppLocale(secondLocaleCode)
                    //recreate()
                    startActivity(Intent(this,AccountScreen::class.java))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getSecondLanguageCode(): String {
        return if(firstLocaleCode == "en") "bn" else "en"
    }

    private fun initRadioButtonUI() {
        if(currentSystemLocaleCode in LocaleUtil.supportedLocales){
            binding.op1.text = getString(R.string.phone_language, getLanguageNameByCode(firstLocaleCode))
        } else {
            binding.op1.text = getLanguageNameByCode(firstLocaleCode)
        }
        binding.op2.text = getLanguageNameByCode(secondLocaleCode)
        if(storage.getPreferredLocale() == secondLocaleCode)  binding.op2.isChecked = true
        else  binding.op1.isChecked = true
    }

    private fun getLanguageNameByCode(code: String) : String{
        val tempLocale = Locale(code)
        return tempLocale.getDisplayLanguage(tempLocale)
    }

    private fun updateAppLocale(locale: String) {
        Log.d("CheckLanguageLocale", "onCreate: update locale call with--$locale")
        storage.setPreferredLocale(locale)
        LocaleUtil.applyLocalizedContext(applicationContext, locale)
    }
}

and this is what I have done on the base activity
 private lateinit var oldPrefLocaleCode : String
    protected val storage : Storage by lazy {
        (application as MyApp).storage
    }
    private fun resetTitle() {
        try {
            val label = packageManager.getActivityInfo(componentName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).labelRes;
            if (label != 0) {
                setTitle(label);
            }
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {}
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        resetTitle()
    }
    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        Log.d("CheckLanguageLocale", "attach base context get call from base activity")
        oldPrefLocaleCode = Storage(newBase).getPreferredLocale()
        applyOverrideConfiguration(LocaleUtil.getLocalizedConfiguration(oldPrefLocaleCode))
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        val currentLocaleCode = Storage(this).getPreferredLocale()
        if(oldPrefLocaleCode != currentLocaleCode){
            //recreate() //locale is changed, restart the activty to update
            oldPrefLocaleCode = currentLocaleCode
        }
        super.onResume()
    }

Now the main problem is whenever I am changing the language the recourses are not changing like if language changed to Bengali language are not changed but the locale code is updating. And seocndly if I call recreate the app is crashing.
